# How to stop re-rendering entire table if one row changes?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using antd table component. [image]

I'm storing this table data in a state. after clicking on modify and modifying something, I'm again making an API call to get the latest data. And I'm updating the state with the latest data. But after fetching the latest data, rows are getting shuffled. If I modified the 3rd row, on re-render due to the latest data, it won't be on the 3rd row. It'll be on some other row.

Comment: Can you post your code for fetching data and render method?

Comment: Seems like your API response returns the data sorted by some specific logic. And if you don't have a sort method of your own then it will display in order it was received. You can either create a sort method of your own which will sort by some kind of id. Get your API response in a different order if that is possible

Comment: I'm using redux for state management. I'm dispatching fetch action after modifying. And yes I'm rendering the data as I received from API. It indeed seems sorted in some manner. Having my own sorting seems a decent idea. thannkyou